# Selecting ActiveRecord object by parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I've got an `Item` model in my Rails/Heroku/Postgres app that acts as a document, with some text, a `removed` flag and many child models called `Version`s.

I've got millions of rows in my production database of `Version` objects where the parent `Item` has had the `removed` flag set to yes by the user, and I want to delete these versions from the database (and leave the `item` objects where they are).

I'm struggling to select all the versions where the parent item's `removed` flag is set to true. Here's my code in `version.rb`:

```
Version.all(:joins => :item, :limit => 20, conditions: { :items => { :removed => true } } ).each do |v|
  v.delete
end
```

Which produces this:

```
SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "versions"."item_id" WHERE "items"."removed" = 't' LIMIT 20
DELETE FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."id" = 1
... lots of DELETE FROM "versions"
```

When I run this locally it only deletes version objects, but when I run the first SQL statement as a dataclip in Heroku Postgres it selects the item objects as well. I know inner join is meant to select from both tables but I don't really understand what's happening here. I need to keep the `item` objects intact. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a style thing, but I would have written the query like this:

```
Version.joins(:item).where(items: { removed: true })
```

Neither this Rails nor the sql it produces should return any `Item`s. I imagine it's the dataclip that introduces weirdness. I would try pulling down your database locally and running it locally in the Rails console.

Also, once you are sure it only returns what you want, you can speed up the process a ton by doing: `Version.joins(:item).where(items: { removed: true }).destroy_all`

This will sidestep Rails (and avoid firing any callbacks) and just execute the find and destroy in the same sql query.

Comment: This is a good answer but according to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all it's `delete_all` that's more efficient (avoids callbacks). I'll do some more research and will probably accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another issue is that `destroy_all` can't be used with a `limit`. Without the limit, the query takes forever to run. Any ideas how I can edit your code to include a limit?

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. I usually prefer to use `destroy_all` and go through Rails unless I'm completely sure I don't want callbacks.

Comment: This seems like extra work, but I suspect it's fairly efficient: `ids = Version.joins(:item).where(items: { removed: true }).limit(20).pluck(:id)` and then `Version.where(id: ids).delete_all`

Comment: That produces `SELECT  id FROM "versions" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "versions"."item_id" WHERE "items"."removed" = 't' LIMIT 20` which causes this error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous`. I changed it to `pluck("versions.id")` and it works fine

Comment: Upvoting for the approach on the joins! :)